# Cargar URL con JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Como puedo hacer para cargar esta web `devocionmusical.com` con *JavaScript*?

Además quiero agregar esto al final **?fromMyApp=true**

Después, en caso que el usuario navegue a otra sección de la web, ej: `devocionmusical.com/songs` que también se le agregue esto al final **?fromMyApp=true**

Muchas gracias!

UPDATE:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>BlankTemplate7771</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function()
    {
        var url, hdiv = document.getElementById("hiddendivid");

        if (hdiv != null)
            url = hdiv.innerText || hdiv.textContent;

        if (url)
        {
            if (top == self)
                window.location = url;
            else
                top.updateWindowWithContentsOfUrl(self, url);
        }
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="hiddendivid" style="display:none">http://devocionmusical.com</div>
</body>
</html>
```

UPDATE 2: Parte del código en devocionmusical.com

```
{if isset($_conf.jrAudio_block_download) && $_conf.jrAudio_block_download == 'off' && $item.profile_quota_id != 9}

{if isset($_post['fromMyApp'])}
<div class="add_to_cart_section" title="Free Download"><span class="add_to_cart_price">GRATIS APP</span><a href="external://{$jamroom_url}/{$murl}/download/audio_file/{$item._item_id}" title="download">{jrCore_icon icon="download" size="24"}</a></div>
{else}
<div class="add_to_cart_section" title="Free Download"><span class="add_to_cart_price">GRATIS</span><a href="      {$jamroom_url}/{$murl}/download/audio_file/{$item._item_id}" title="download">    {jrCore_icon icon="download" size="24"}</a></div>
{/if}

{else}

<div class="add_to_cart_section" title="Download Not Available"><span class="add_to_cart_price">N/A</span>{jrCore_icon icon="lock" size="24"}</div>

{/if}
```

Comment: intentastes agregar un iframe?

Comment: Quieres cargar el contenido de esa url en un <fragment> o simplemente ir a esa url cuando des click en algun lugar... no entiendo muy bien la prengunta. Por favor explicar mejor

Comment: Por favor, usa palabras adecuadas para que se entienda lo que tratas de decir. Te recomiendo consultar la guía [Cómo preguntar](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: debieras poner la pregunta anterior que hiciste a este respecto. De paso, ¿Por qué quieres enviar ese parámetro? Si es para rastrear de dónde vino la visita, podrías capturar el parámetro en la primera visita, fijarle una cookie al visitante, y en las páginas siguientes deducir el parámetro leyendo la cookie

Comment: @amenadiel Necesito tener ese parametro en el url porque tengo un condicional en mi archivo html que ejecuta un codigo siempre y cuando encuentre ese parametro. Gracias por ayuda! te puedo contactar de forma mas directa?

Comment: No. Ayudar de forma directa se convertiría en algo esclavizante, y no siempre tengo tiempo. De hecho me meto acá para despejar la mente de mi trabajo que de por sí es estresante. Volviendo al tema: postea el código de tu HTML a ver si se nos ocurre cómo sustituir el query string con una variable de sesión o una cookie

Comment: @amenadiel ahi lo agregué. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Ya, pero me refería a una parte del código de devocionmusical. Para entender dónde capturas el parámetro "fromMyApp=true", si es por javascript o php, por ejemplo, o si es algo que usas sólo para google analytics para saber qué visitas vienen del app

Comment: @amenadiel ahi lo agregué. El codigo de devocionmusical es Smarty

Comment: Ya entiendo (un poco), pero lo que debieras comprobar es `isset($_GET['fromMyApp'])`.  ¿Te está funcionando la primera parte? es decir ¿Carga el contenido de devocionmusical.com? ¿Tienes acceso a añadirle ese parámetro a la URL inicial con que carga tu sitio?

Comment: @amenadiel Asi tal cual esta si me funciona. Si te fijas cuando encuentra esa variable en el url, muestra el texto "GRATIS APP" con el link. Tengo acceso a añadirle ese parametro a la url inicial DENTRO DE LA APP. A eso te referías?

Comment: A eso me refería. Y puedes mostrar el código PHP que llama al template de smarty? Se me ocurre que se puede usar una variable de sesión, aunque sea poco elegante.

Comment: @amenadiel Uy, la verdad ahi me mataste.. no se cual seria el código php :/

Comment: Pero entonces quien le hace render a la plantilla smarty?

Comment: La verdad no sabria decirte. El CMS que uso se llama Jamroom (jamroom.net)

Answer (score 1):

Si deseas cargar el dominio `http://devocionmusical.com/` desde un dominio diferente con javascript lo más probable es que no puedas. Los navegadores prohíben esto, gracias a `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` a menos que dicho dominio añada la línea `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: <SITIO_WEB>` dentro del codigo del lado del servidor.

Sin embargo, con un poco de HTML puedes utilizar la técnica de los `iframe`, tal como a continuación:

```
<iframe src="http://devocionmusical.com/?fromMyApp=true"></iframe>
<-- Es aquí en donde puedes agregar la variable que necesitas -->
```

Si estás creando una aplicación en Android, una sección en el mismo dominio, o una extensión de Chrome, puedes hacer uso de la librería `jQuery` para JavaScript.

En este caso consta de lo siguiente:

```
jQuery.get("http://devocionmusical.com/?fromMyApp=true", function(respuesta){
// respuesta = contiene los datos que envía el dominio.
});
```